# Why does iptables not fetch information from /etc/sysconfig/iptables on CentOS?

Tags: centos, iptables

I'm new to Linux and encountered a problem with `iptables`.

Here is the content of my `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Tue Nov 27 21:41:04 2012
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [40672:2356787]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Nov 27 21:41:04 2012
```

But when I try `sudo iptables -L -n -v -x`, I have the following output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 261172 packets, 1040204290 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 522761 packets, 2080465034 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Why aren't the rules from `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` displayed in output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does iptables not fetch information from `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`
> on CentOS?

Because the iptables service is not enabled in startup.

You can check using:

```
chkconfig --list iptables
```

When the iptables service gets started,
it loads rules from `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` using:

```
iptables-restore /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

So check whether the iptables service is running or not:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/iptables status
```